# Getting error TS1204 on 1.5.0-beta (target: ES6), however, everything works fine

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

Looks like everything gets compiled correctly from Typescript to ES6 to ES5. However, I keep getting the following error. I can't figure out what is causing this error...

```
error TS1204: Cannot compile external modules into amd or commonjs when targeting es6 or higher.
```

Setup:

- typescript 1.5.0-beta installed (npm install -g typescript@1.5.0-beta)
- tsconfig.json file shown below.
- Two folders are used src (all the *.ts files) and typings (external library *.d.ts files).
- Atom editor fills in everything in "files" property in tsconfig.json
- ES6 files are compiled to ES5 using Babel

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.5.0-beta",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "build"
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./src/**/*.ts",
        "./typings/**/*.ts",
        "!./node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "files": [ redacted ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells it all:

> Cannot compile external **modules** into amd or **commonjs when targeting es6** or higher.

ES6 has modules built in, so remove this line from `tsconfig.json`:

```
"module": "commonjs",
```

Then since you're compiling from ES6 to ES5 with babel, tell it to compile to CommonJS:

```
 babel --modules common ...etc...
```